# Elementary row operations in matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

This is really such a lovely math community, I am working on some differential equations hw and my teacher didn't teach this topic yet so I am a little confused. My first question is pertaining to part A where i am not sure what is being asked by "P12, permute the 1st and 2nd rows" do I multiply all the matrices elements by -1 because that is the number in the first row second column of the matrices? And after I complete part A am i suppose to continue to do part b with the new matrices from part A or am i suppose to continue to do part b from the original A=[] matrices that was given? If someone can help me answer these questions I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To permute the rows you just swap them.

The matrix with permuted rows is $\left(\matrix{3&-9&-6\\-4&-1&2}\right)$ Now you continue the next step with this new matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help!